# angularjs satellizer redirect back to previous page

Tags: angularjs, satellizer

I am using satellizer in my angular code to handle my authentication with local api. I am not integrating any third party API authentication with my site, everything is local. I get the website working, if the user is with invalid token, system will redirect the user to login page. What if I need to bring the requested link back after the user login, how do I do that?

for example. If the user request to access '/customer/detail/123', but user is redirected to the login page (/account/login), after the login is successful, how could I redirect the user back to '/customer/detail/123'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Satellizer is not helping you with this problem. I also ran into this and created a service to handle this. So if a user is redirected to /login, I save the path in a service. After login, redirect to the saved path by getting it out of the service.

1. When using ui-router, detect every change by listening to '$stateChangeStart'. When the state changes and a login is needed, save the current path by getting it from: '$location.path()'
2. After login, set the path to $location.path();

Hope this helps.
Lieuwe

Answer (score 1):

I am doing exactly same thing in my project. Check this.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {

    if(next.name != 'user_login' && next.name != 'user_register')
    {
        // I am using localStorage module but you can do the same 
        // using your way of storing values to localstorage
        localStorageService.set('redirect_back_path', next.name);
        localStorageService.set('redirect_back_path_params', current);
    }
});
```

Here I am storing two values, `redirect_back_path` to store the state name of current request, on every request and `redirect_back_path_params` to store the parameters this current request have, "like 123 in your example".

I don't know why angular saves parameters of upcoming request to `current` object. Maybe someone else can answer here.

Ok, Now what you need to do is, after login, check if there is any value in `redirect_back_path` and if yes,

```
$state.go(localStorageService.get('redirect_back_path'), localStorageService.get('redirect_back_path_params');
```

otherwise just go to any other default page.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same questionning with satellizer

Since ui-router 1.0.0-alpha1, $stateChangeStart and such events aren't supported anymore : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2655

I'm using the following and it's working perfectly :

satellizer 0.15.5, ui-router 1.0.0-beta.3, angular 1.6.1

```
app.run(['$transitions', '$state', '$auth', 'CommonService', function ($transitions, $state, $auth, CommonService) {
    $transitions.onStart({}, function (transition) {
        var state = transition.to();
        if (state.resolve && state.resolve.loginRequired && !$auth.isAuthenticated())
        {
            CommonService.RedirectState = state.name;
            return $state.target('login');
        }
        else if (CommonService.RedirectState && $auth.isAuthenticated())
        {
            var target = $state.target(CommonService.RedirectState);
            CommonService.RedirectState = null;
            return target;
        }
    });
}]).service('CommonService', [ 
    function ()
    {
        this.RedirectState = null;
    }]);
```

When the user is asking a restricted (resolve : loginRequired) state and isn't authenticated, we are storing the state in the service and redirect him to the 'login' state.

later on when the user is authenticated and we found that there's a 'RedirectState' in the service (even if satellizer redirect to '/' by default), we simply redirect the user to 'CommonService.RedirectState' and delete the reference in the service. No localstorage /other module needed. No change were made into the satelizer default config. I simply added this after the route config.

Answer (score 0):

Base on DavidT, I changed to redirect with original parameters:

```
app.run(['$transitions', '$state', '$auth', 'CommonService', function ($transitions, $state, $auth, CommonService) {
    $transitions.onStart({}, function (transition) {
        var state = transition.to();
        var para = transition.targetState();
        if (state.resolve && state.resolve.loginRequired && !$auth.isAuthenticated())
        {
            CommonService.RedirectState = state.name;
            CommonService.RedirectParams = para;
            return $state.target('login');
        }
        else if (CommonService.RedirectState && $auth.isAuthenticated())
        {
            var target = $state.target(CommonService.RedirectState, CommonService.RedirectParams._params);
            CommonService.RedirectState = null;
            CommonService.RedirectParams = null;
            return target;
        }
    });
}]).service('CommonService', [ 
    function ()
    {
        this.RedirectState = null;
        this.RedirectParams = null;
    }]);
```